eclipse 2024-06 still opens, although eclipse 2023-06 exists in it's directory only
I am newly employed in a company that use eclipse for a project. I started using eclipse 2024-06, but had to rollback to eclipse 2023-06, as we use the Activiti diagram editor that is not running on all eclipse versions. Having two eclipses on the notebook under Windows 11 Pro should not be a problem, but sometimes, it started the newer version, although I had permanently switched to the older one.
To get rid of this, I first zipped the jee-2024-06 directory. As eclipse 2024-06 insisted opening, I deleted the zip file and the unzipped directory from the disk. This worked very well until today.
I tried to install the DBeaver AI as an eclipse plugin, which took a long time. The installer tried 15 different ways, and started again to search. Then, it started to install the plugin. For a long time, the installation was at 36%, but continued about ten minutes later. At the end, the plugin was installed.
Interestingly, when I click on the taskbar the eclipse icon, all of a sudden, eclipse 2024-06 started to open again. I searched the disk for a jee-2024-06 directory, but no avail. I asked ChatGPT 4.0, which advised me among others to delete the .metadata directory, but still, eclipse 2024-06 opens, asking me whether or not to proceed with the workspace that was changed by an older eclipse version.
My question: how is it possible to get the newest version that has once been in use on the notebook again, after the directory and even the corresponding ZIP file has been deleted?!?

I would prefer the newest stable version, if I could use the Activiti diagram editor used in one of the projects, but this editor runs on eclipse 2023-06 and perhaps on some older versions.

You've included the Eclipse 2024-06 splash screen, but once the product is loaded, is it actually 2024-06, or is it really 2023-06? Look carefully at the layout and the available features, including the About dialog and verify the actual product.

Deleting the .metadata directory is almost always the wrong thing to do. Before anything can be done to straighten things out, how did you get the two versions onto your system in the first place?

Never ever delete the .metadata folder! That's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow that can lead to data loss and wreck your workspace. Instead, try a fresh workspace. In general, you shouldn't delete files you don't know about, not even if a random guy on Stack Overflow or a chatbot suggests it. Please help to prevent the further spreading of this hoax by not mention it as a solution in your question. Several Eclipse installations are working without problems, so it must be something else that has corrupted your installation. If a fresh workspace does not work, then do a fresh installation.

What @MarsAtomic says. IME, Eclipse seems to have a bug (if unintentional) that sometimes shows the splashscreen as the latest available version, but what loads is still the original. I've seen this occur with only 1 Eclipse installation present on a system.

Thank you for your replies! I wanted to use eclipse 2024-06 as the newest stable version, but run into problems with the Activiti diagram editor needed in the project. This plugin works only on some eclipse versions, the newest one being eclipse 2023-06. So, I decided to switch to the older version. Interestingly, after a problematic plugin installation (tried 15×, then started over again), eclipse "decided" to switch to the new version, although I had deleted it.

@majixin An IDE package consists of various parts that can be updated individually. One part contains the splash screen. An up-to-date splash screen does not guarantee that everything is up-to-date which is the expected behavior, not a bug. For details see Help > About Eclipse IDE > Installation Details, tab Installed Software which list all the parts and their versions.

@Sae1962 Could you please first help to prevent the further spreading of the hoax that caused problems for many by editing your question (yes, there are people following questions instead of following answers).

@howlger  I can confirm that Eclipse has not undergone any updates when I see this. I sometimes see it change session to session, as in: launch Eclipse, see the updated splash screen, exit, relaunch, see a different splash screen. If you know the reproducible reason for this, it would be of interest, but I've never concerned myself with it. "An up-to-date splash screen does not guarantee that everything is up-to-date..." - never said/implied that. I said Eclipse "sometimes shows the splashscreen as the latest available version, but what loads is still the original" (unupdated)

@majixin I cannot reproduce what you are saying. Does this happen sporadically or always? Which versions are you talking about exactly? Did you use the Eclipse Installer? How did you do the update? Does this still happen when in eclipse.ini you removed the two lines -showsplash and org.eclipse.epp.package.common?

@howler Sporadic. I develop a commercial plugin product supporting Luna SR2 onwards for over 5 years. I often start Eclipse perhaps hundreds of times per day, so it seems a bit odd that this happens, so I know what the OP is seeing. I don't have 2024-06 installed anywhere currently. I do have 2024-03 and sometimes its splashscreen will show 2024-06. It doesn't affect the product, so not too concerned, but it does happen.

@howlger Sorry - forgot to answer all your Qs. I download Eclipse zips - and just unzip in a location. I do not use Oomph or any installer. I've not tried removing the -showsplash of eclipse.ini - wouldn't that just not show a splashscreen so mask the issue? I'm not the OP, he sees something similar for other reasons I suspect. I thought he was experiencing what I am, but on re-read it's clearly not the case.

The -showsplash in the eclipse.ini is to show the splash screen faster, by the Eclipse executable before the Java VM is started. The splash screen is specified in the config.ini file (e.g. osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common). When using a ZIP file, make sure to extract it into an empty directory and not into a directory that already contains an Eclipse installation.

As I have to start with the project, I switched to IntelliJ.

@Sae1962 When you get time to check back, go to your 2023-06 Eclipse installation folder and drill down to plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_<version> folder and see if there's a splash.bmp file there. Open it to make sure it's the one for 2023-06 and hasn't somehow got updated to the one for 2024-06. If you're launching 2023-06, I suspect seeing a splash for 2024-06 is a red-herring. Maybe try what howlger suggested about removing -splashscreen entry from eclipse.ini and see if the problem persists. I suspect launching 2023-06 and seeing 2024-06 is a splashscreen issue.
